# Where are initial LOCALE settings stored?

Tags: debian, language, locale

does anybody know, where the initial setting for $LANGUAGE is stored or where to find respective information?

Background: During the installation of debian sid I choose to have german, english (GB), italien and spanish available (perhaps a stupid idea):

> "# locale
>   ... LANGUAGE=de:en_GB:it:es ..."

Except LC_ALL ="" all others are set as ecpected to LANG="de_DE.UTF-8" and LC_*="de_DE.UTF-8".

I know how to "fix" this settings in profile, bashrc ... but I am interested to understand, where Debian store this "initial" setting.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

- `/etc/default/locale` is the current fashion
- `/etc/environment` was the earlier but is now deprecated
- `$HOME/.pam_environment` is where gui-setters keep their stuff